# Camera as background view?

Tags: iphone, ios4, camera

I would like to test around a bit with augmented reality. My first problem is how to get the picture that comes from the camera as background for my view? For what i want to do, i dont need to access the picture, i just need it as background. I found a few solutions how to take a picture with the camera, but nothing that gives me a picture that comes from the camera.

thanks,.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use AVFoundation for that.

You need to set up an AVCaptureSession with an AVCaptureDevice and an AVCaptureDeviceInput. Finally - and this is what you're interested in - set up an AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.

Send the startRunning: message to your AVCaptureSession object, and you should be good to go.

Docs here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/03_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW14

Comment: but what if he wants to do some GL over the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer? AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer is a bit of a black box, he'll soon have to reimplement it.

Comment: I have no experience with GL, so I wouldn't know about that. I have, however, successfully used UIViews on top of AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.

Answer (score 1):

another way would be using `UIImagePickerController` .
Create an instance, say picker and set: `picker.showsCameraControls = NO` .
And finally set `cameraOverlayView` with your overlay: `picker.cameraOverlayView = someViewController.view`.
Hope this helps.